# How can I use TFS WebApi to remove a workitemlink

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi and trying to add and remove a workitemlink from an item.

I am calling

```
workItemTrackingHttpClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(jsonPatchDocument, Id);
```

and my JsonPatchDocument looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "op": 1,
    "Path": "/relations/-",
    "From": null,
    "Value": {
      "Rel": "System.LinkTypes.Dependency-Forward",
      "Url": "https://[server]/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/[id]"
    }
  }
]
```

When I use "op": 0 to update (add) it works correctly but I cannot work out the correct form for remove.

I get an error similar to

> VssServiceException
>
> Remove does not support insert. 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi 
>   -2146232832

Anyone have any ideas please.

Comment: About the method below, do you have any other question?

Comment: Thank you that helped me solve the problem. I just need to load the existing workitem and iterate over the relations to find the index of the one I need to delete. Its a little inefficient but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove a link, the JsonPatchDocument is not like the insert, it is necessary to provide "value".

It is like:

```
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "op": "remove",
    "path": "/relations/0"
  }
]
```

To remove a link, you need to point which link to be removed by using `"relations/Id"`. The Id is started from 0.

For more induction, please refer to the [official document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#remove-a-link).